# remove tuple brackets for .ppm file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, tuples

I have this Code that should reverse the pixels of a `.ppm` image.

I was able to reverse the pixels but I'm stuck in removing the lists of lists and tuple brackets in order to get the integers only.

I want:

```
 0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0   15  0 15
 0  0  0  0 15  7    0  0  0    0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0
15  0 15  0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0
```

what I got:

```
('15', '0', '15') ('0', '0', '0') ('0', '0', '0') ('0', '0', '0')
('0', '0', '0') ('0', '0', '0') ('0', '15', '7') ('0', '0', '0')
('0', '0', '0') ('0', '15', '7') ('0', '0', '0') ('0', '0', '0')
('0', '0', '0') ('0', '0', '0') ('0', '0', '0') ('15', '0', '15')
```

code:

```
takePPM = input("Enter the pmm file name: ")
try:
    openFile = open(takePPM, "r")
    readFile = openFile.readlines()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
    exit(1)
lists = []
for row in readFile[3:]:
    lists.append(row.split())

#convert each list in lists to lists of 3-tuples
target = []
for list in lists:
    target.append([tuple(list[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(list),3)])
revList = []
for i in reversed(target):
    revList.append(i)

#newFile = open("Mirror_" + takePPM, "w")
for row in revList:
    #newFile.write(*row)
    removeList = tuple(row)
    print(*removeList)
```

the commented lines are to print the new reversed pixels to a new file, but want to check I got the correct format first

Comment: `''.join(list[i:i+3])` maybe in the list comprehension

Comment: Yes this works, thank you very much 

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the last line of code, `print(*removeList)` with

```
print(' '.join(''.join(t) for t in removeList))
```

Testing it out:

```
revList = [[('15', '0', '15'), ('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0')]]
for row in revList:
     #newFile.write(*row)
     removeList = tuple(row)
     print(' '.join(''.join(t) for t in removeList))

# 15015 000 000 000
```

Comment: I have edited the 'what I want section' apparently this is the was its supposed to be.. sorry for the mistake. also when I input the ```.ppm``` file I get 3 black and white upside down of the original picture. do you know by any chance how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe  `print('  '.join(' '.join(t) for t in reversed(removeList)))` , giving `0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0  15 0 15` for the first line